# Applicative Distributor for List `dist` Function

Tags: haskell

I think that I copied the following `dist` function from [Applicative Programming with Effects](http://staff.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/Applicative.html):

The paper prefaces this function with:

> Have you noticed that sequence and transpose now look rather alike?
>   The details that distinguish the two programs are inferred by the
>   compiler from their types. Both are instances of the applicative
>   distributor for lists

```
dist :: Applicative f => [f a] -> f [a]
dist []       = [[]]
dist (v : vs) = [(:) v (dist vs)]
```

However, I get the following compile-time error:

```
ghci> :l ApplicativePaper.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( ApplicativePaper.hs, interpreted )

ApplicativePaper.hs:12:20:
    Could not deduce (a ~ f a)
    from the context (Applicative f)
      bound by the type signature for
                 dist :: Applicative f => [f a] -> f [a]
      at ApplicativePaper.hs:10:9-39
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for dist :: Applicative f => [f a] -> f [a]
          at ApplicativePaper.hs:10:9
    Relevant bindings include
      vs :: [f a] (bound at ApplicativePaper.hs:12:9)
      v :: f a (bound at ApplicativePaper.hs:12:7)
      dist :: [f a] -> f [a] (bound at ApplicativePaper.hs:11:1)
    In the first argument of `(:)', namely `v'
    In the expression: (:) v (dist vs)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong. Also, please provide an intuition for this function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the paper, the double bracket `〚 f u1 … un 〛` is defined on page 4 to be the same as `pure f <*> u1 <*> … <*> un`.

The definition of `dist` in the text is

```
dist :: Applicative f ⇒ [f a] → f [a ]
dist []       = 〚 [] 〛
dist (v : vs) = 〚 (:) v (dist vs) 〛
```

Translating the other symbols into Haskell and making the substitution for the definition of `〚 … 〛` results in

```
dist :: Applicative f => [f a] -> f [a ]
dist []       = pure []
dist (v : vs) = pure (:) <*> v <*> (dist vs)
```

Comment: Or simply `dist (v:vs) = (:) <$> v <*> dist vs`.

Comment: @AaditMShah whilst that's correct, the definition through `pure` is more consistent: lift the first element of the "list" with `pure`, then join everything with `<*>`. That way `〚 [] 〛` is justifiably `pure []`.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong brackets. Conor McBride and Ross Paterson use so called idiom brackets. Here is your definition in imaginary syntax (but it probably compiles with the Strathclyde Haskell Enhancement, I'm not sure):

```
dist :: Applicative f => [f a] -> f [a]
dist []       = (| [] |)
dist (v : vs) = (| (:) v (dist vs) |)
```

`(| f x y z |)` elaborates to `pure f <*> x <*> y <*> z`. So `dist` defined right is

```
dist :: Applicative f => [f a] -> f [a]
dist  []      = pure []
dist (v : vs) = (:) <$> v <*> dist vs -- f <$> x == pure f <*> x
```

There is a very similar function, defined in the `Control.Monad` module:

```
-- | Evaluate each action in the sequence from left to right,
-- and collect the results.
sequence       :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a] 
{-# INLINE sequence #-}
sequence ms = foldr k (return []) ms
            where
              k m m' = do { x <- m; xs <- m'; return (x:xs) }
```

Only it requires a monad instead of an applicative.

There is also a generalization of `dist`, provided by the `Traversable` typeclass:

```
sequenceA :: Applicative f => t (f a) -> f (t a)
```

So you have some `t` (which is both a `Functor` and a `Foldable`) instead of `[]` here.

This description of `sequence`

```
-- | Evaluate each action in the sequence from left to right,
-- and collect the results.
```

is pretty exhaustive. For example

```
main = dist [print 3, print 4, print 5]
```

prints

```
3
4
5
```

Since every monad is an applicative, `dist` works properly here with the IO monad. However there is no need in collecting the results here. That's why there is the `sequence_` function, that returns `()` as the result.

It's easy to define `dist_`:

```
dist_ :: Applicative f => [f a] -> f ()
dist_  []      = pure ()
dist_ (v : vs) = v *> dist_ vs
```

So you simply perform all actions in a list.

For example

```
main = do
    print $ dist_ [Just 3, Just 4, Just 5]
    print $ dist_ [Nothing, Just 3]
```

prints

```
Just ()
Nothing
```

because

```
Just smth1 *> Just smth2 == Just smth2
Nothing    *> Just smth2 == Nothing
```

The only thing, that `dist` adds to this machinery, is collecting results.

So

```
main = do
    print $ dist [Just 3, Just 4, Just 5]
    print $ dist [Just 3, Nothing]
```

prints

```
Just [3,4,5]
Nothing
```

Also, have a look at the [Typeclassopedia](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia).