# Understanding `mapA` to Gain Intuition

Tags: haskell

I'm working on an exercise from Brent Yorgey's 2013 UPenn [lecture](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/lectures/11-applicative2.html) to implement `mapA`.

`mapA :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> ([a] -> f [b])`

I'm trying to gain intuition for this function. How is this function useful? I'm not questioning its utility - just trying to understand it.

Additionally, I'm looking for a hint to go from `a -> f b` to `[a] -> f [b]`.

Comment: Would you agree that `mapM` is useful? I think it is obvious that "perform this action on every element of the collection" is a ubiquitous concept. This is what `mapM/A` are. `mapA` is `mapM` for Applicative. Since not every Applicative is a Monad, you may sometimes want a function with the "shape" of `mapM` which only requires the Applicative constraint. Hence, `mapA`.

Comment: `mapA f = dist . map f`, where `dist` is from your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350924/applicative-distributor-for-list-dist-function).

Comment: You can also find a implenmentation of this function in the list instance of [`Data.Traversable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/src/Data-Traversable.html)

Comment: [The essence of the iterator pattern](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/iterator.pdf) describe several uses for the idiom, using the more general `traverse` function.

Answer (score 3):

If we knew nothing at all about `f` then a function like `a -> f b` would let us put things into `f`-boxes but then we'd be completely stuck. You're probably familiar with `Functor`. If we know `f` were a `Functor` then we'd be able to transform the thing inside of `f`, but we're still basically stuck---`f` forms an unmoving wall we cannot cross.

Why do we care? Well, when we try to construct the function `[a] -> f [b]` we need to some how operate on a collection of `a`s. We could, perhaps, just pull the first one off if we liked (and it existed) and  feed it through `a -> f b` then wrap the result in a list:

```
unsatisfying :: Functor f => (a -> f b) -> ([a] -> f [b])
unsatisfying inject (a : _) = fmap (\x -> [x]) (inject a)
```

but not only do we have an incomplete pattern match on `[a]`, we're clearly violating something in the spirit of this function---we'd much prefer to use all of the `a`s. Unfortunately, knowing only `f` or even that `f` is a `Functor` gets us only as far as

```
stillUnsatisfying :: Functor f => (a -> f b) -> ([a] -> [f b])
stillUnsatisfying inject as = map inject as
```

The problem is that just because we have a collection of `f`-containers doesn't mean we can find any way to treat them collectively. We'd like to somehow "glue" our collection `[f b]` all together. If we could do that then a function like `[a] -> f [b]` would sound like "explode our list `[a]` into pieces, pass them each individually into `f` using `inject`, glom all of the `(f b)`s together, and then reassemble the list on the inside".

Clearly we need a way to "glom" `Functor`s together and also a way to operate on the separate pieces "on the inside" of `f`.

So this is where `Applicative` comes in. I'm not going to introduce it exactly, though. Instead, let's look at an equivalent type class

```
class Functor f => Monoidal f where
  basic :: a -> f a
  glom  :: f a -> f b -> f (a, b)
```

It's an interesting exercise to prove that `Monoidal` and `Applicative` are equivalent, but immediately you can see that `glom` provides exactly what we're looking for. Moreover, `basic`/`pure` give us the ability to inject raw pieces of our list into `f` as we need them (for instance, if our `[a]` is empty then we'll need to inject an empty list into `f` without using `a -> f b` as we cannot---that looks like `basic [] :: f [b]`).

So `Applicative` provides you the ability to not only transform inside of functors but also to glom a bunch of functors together and operate on all of their pieces inside of the functor.

Comment: "but immediately you can see that glom provides exactly what we're looking". I can't.

Comment: Normally we'd have `(<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` but we can get that with `glom` as `f <*> a = fmap ($) (glom f a)`. Try it out!

Comment: But why is the equivalence of Monoidal and Applicative relevant to the original question (which is how to implement mapA)?

Comment: Because `Monoidal` more clearly indicates how `Applicative`'s core is the ability to smash functors together using a standard product. This is obscured by the `Applicative` formulation.

Answer (score 1):

You're halfway there, but the final function you're looking for is the `sequenceA` function that's defined in LYAH. Here's my implementation:

```
sequenceA :: Applicative f => [f a] -> f [a]
sequenceA = foldr ((<*>) . fmap (:)) (pure [])
```

From there the `mapA` function is easy as pie. Just add another argument and compose the two functions:

```
mapA :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> [a] -> f [b]
mapA f xs = foldr ((<*>) . fmap (:) . f) (pure []) xs
-- Or, you could implement it this more elegant, albeit slightly slower, way:
mapA = (sequenceA .) . map
```

And there you have an implementation for you to have a look at. As for the usefulness, it's particularly useful in IO, when you have a list like `["Foo","Bar","Baz"]`, and you'd like to `putStrLn` all of those functions. Do do so, you will need to map each value and the `sequence` it, which `mapA` does. Note that these functions have monadic equivalents, but it's a good exercise to implement them in purely `Applicative` ways.

These functions are both quite useful when dealing with lists of `Applicative`s, allowing one to more easily manipulate the values inside them without using half a ton of `fmap`s.

Answer (score 0):

We already know that `map :: (a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])` is useful.  It applies a function to every element of a list.

A loose but enlightening interpretation of `a -> f b` for an applicative `f` is that it is a function which takes an `a`, performs an applicative "action", and returns a `b`.  For example if `f` is `IO` then the "action" might be reading from a disk.  `mapA :: (a -> f b) -> ([a] -> f [b])` can be interpreted as applying this "function" to every element of the list.